# PWA with React: Trying to create a object that updates every second and is accessible for many components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, react-context

I'm currently working on a PWA build with React.

I'm looking for a way to create one object which contains information like the current time (incl. seconds), current date, the users location, the users speed. These information must update exactly every second. Also the infos must be shown on the screen and therefore the screen needs to re-render every time one of the infos changes.
Additionally I want to access these infos from different components. (that's why I was trying to use reacts useContext)

If have tried many different approaches using useState, useEffect, useContext, setIntervall, setTimeout etc. but nothing works completely.

Either the values are not updated regularly or I get into an infinite loop in which new intervals are created over and over again and the performance drops.

If you now what my problem is or have an idea on how to implement this it would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Here is my current version:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

//just initializing the context with some dummy values
const DrivingContext = createContext({
  currentDate: "01.01.2022",
  currentTime: "00:00:00",
  currentSpeed: "0 km/h",
  currentLatLng: { lat: 50, lng: 6 },
  currentAddress: "City",
});

export function DrivingContextProvider(props) {
 //creating a state object so that the components will re-render 
 //(don't know if that's necessary)
 const [infos, setInfos] = useState({
    date: DrivingContext.currentDate,
    time: DrivingContext.currentTime,
    speed: DrivingContext.currentSpeed,
    latLng: DrivingContext.currentLatLng,
    address: DrivingContext.currentAddress,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(updateValues, 1000);
  }, []);

  function updateValues() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    const timeStr = currentDate.toTimeString().slice(0, 8);
    const dateStr = currentDate.toLocaleDateString();

    var speed = infos.speed;
    var latLngObj = infos.latLng;
    var addressObj = infos.address;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        if (position.coords.speed !== null) {
          speed = position.coords.speed;
        }
        latLngObj = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
        };
        var link =
          "https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/reverse?lat=" +
          position.coords.latitude +
          "&lon=" +
          position.coords.longitude
          "&apiKey=MYKEY";
        var requestOptions = {
          method: "GET",
        };
        fetch(link, requestOptions)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            var addressStr =
              data.features[0].properties.address_line1 +
              ", " +
              data.features[0].properties.postcode +
              " " +
              data.features[0].properties.city;
            addressObj = addressStr;
          });
      });
    }

    setInfos({
      date: dateStr,
      time: timeStr,
      speed: speed,
      latLng: latLngObj,
      address: addressObj,
      fetched: true,
    });
  }
  const context = {
    currentDate: infos.date,
    currentTime: infos.time,
    currentSpeed: infos.speed,
    currentLatLng: infos.latLng,
    currentAddress: infos.address,
    alreadyFetched: infos.fetched,
  };
  return (
    <DrivingContext.Provider value={context}>
      {props.children}
    </DrivingContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default DrivingContext;
```

Comment: Could you show us some of these approaches you have already tried? So that we can maybe correct your mistake?

Comment: @Kapobajza Of course I just updated the question

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-useeffect-cleanup-function/

Comment: You should also avoid running the getCurrentPosition from within the setinterval, and instead use the navigator.geolocation.watchPosition method to update the values. You can set this listener in the useEffect itself.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis alright thank you very much! I will try update my code now. Do you think, in general, using the react context is a good way of doing it or are there simpler/better performing options?

Comment: @matskraft You can use the Context API to do what you want, but if you are updating things quite a lot and you are interested in performance (e.g. avoiding unecessary re-renders) you can probably consider something like Redux or Jotai which perform better under these circumstances. They both use a more precise and selective updating mechanism which improves the performance of applications with large Component hierarchies and frequent updates.